# Which country can be called the successor of the Roman Empire, after 476?

Tags: roman-empire

In a website I usually go, there is a hot issue about which country is the successor of the Roman Empire. The users are not that serious and enjoy this just for fun; but this has been debated for a long time. Here are some so-called candidates:

1. Byzantine(Constantinople was called Roma nova; the people called themselves Romans)
2. Ottomans(I don't think this one is the answer but I put here because this is one of the key candidates in that website; maybe because they occupied Rome, I guess)
3. Russian Empire(called Moscow the 3rd Rome)

Can you guys tell me your opinion, or what celebrated professionals in this field say?

Comment: Care to post which site you got these info from? AFAIK the successor of the Roman Empire is the Eastern Roman Empire, also known as the Byzantine Empire.

Comment: This is in Korean; you might not be able to read the posts unless you speak Korean. http://gall.dcinside.com/board/lists/?id=europa

Comment: How are you (they) defining succession? Occupation of the same territory? Continuation of the same language/culture/values?

Comment: That's the problem. The standard varies by everyone

Comment: I will downvote any question that references a website but does not provide a link/citation.  No way to tell if the website in question is credible or not.

Comment: What about the Holy Roman Empire under Charlemagne?

Comment: It is called "the Fall" because none of the conquering powers recognized themselves as successors (to the point that the imperial symbols were sent back to Constantinople). And I would not call the Bizantine Empire a "successor" because it already had coexisted with the Western Empire for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the Byzantine Empire certainly considered itself to be a continuation of the Roman Empire. It continued Roman culture fairly directly at first, but gradually changed over its lifespan of nearly a thousand years. The Empire had been re-arranged and sub-divided a number of times, but the distinction between the [Greek-speaking East and Latin-speaking West](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_East_and_Latin_West) was the one that lasted, and the Byzantine Empire had started as the Eastern Roman Empire.

The Holy Roman Empire also considered itself to be a continuation of the Roman Empire. It only maintained Latin as a language of the educated after the Romance languages had developed out of Vulgar Latin, and most of the HRE territory was German-speaking anyway. While its culture had Roman influences, it wasn't strictly Roman. It did, however, help preserve Latin Christianity.

The Ottoman Empire regarded itself as a successor to the Byzantine Empire, but it wasn't founded until about 800 years after the fall of the Western Roman Empire, so the claim to be a successor of the original Rome was not taken seriously, and lapsed after the death of Mehmed II.

The Russian claim was based on family links to the last Byzantine emperors, and their support of Orthodox Christianity. "Tsar" is their version of "Cesar".

After the dismantling of the Holy Roman Empire, the Austrian Empire claimed to be its successor, as did the German Empire from 1871. Fascist Italy also claimed to be a new Rome, but they weren't very good at conquest.

The Wikipedia article on [Third Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_Rome) is a reasonable summary of the various claims.

Comment: "Latin Christianity" was never important for the old Western Roman Empire integrity - not in the way Orthodox Christianity was for the Eastern Roman Empire. I would also like to point out that Byzantine Empire never called itself "Byzantine".